# Working with encrypted files in Laravel (how to download decrypted file)

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, file-upload, laravel-5

In my webapp, users can upload files. Before being saved and stored, the contents of the file are encrypted using something like this:

```
Crypt::encrypt(file_get_contents($file->getRealPath()));
```

I then use the file system that comes with Laravel to move the file

```
Storage::put($filePath, $encryptedFile);
```

I have a table to store information about each file with columns such as:

- id
- file_path
- file_name
- original_name (includes the extension)

Now I want the user to be able to download this encrypted file. However, I'm having trouble decrypting the file and returning it to the user. In the [file downloads response section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#file-downloads) of the Laravel documentation, it suggests to do this:

```
return response()->download($pathToFile, $name, $headers);
```

It wants a file path which is fine, but at which point can I decrypt the file contents so that it is actually readable?

I do seem to be able to do this:

```
$encryptedContents = Storage::get($fileRecord->file_path);
$decryptedContents = Crypt::decrypt($encryptedContents);
```

... but I don't know how to return it as a download with a specified file name.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could manually create the response like so:

```
$encryptedContents = Storage::get($fileRecord->file_path);
$decryptedContents = Crypt::decrypt($encryptedContents);

return response()->make($decryptedContents, 200, array(
    'Content-Type' => (new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME))->buffer($decryptedContents),
    'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="' . pathinfo($fileRecord->file_path, PATHINFO_BASENAME) . '"'
));
```

You can check out the [Laravel API](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Contracts/Routing/ResponseFactory.html#method_make) for more info on what the parameters of the `make` method are. The [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.pathinfo.php) function is also used to extract the filename from the path so it sends the correct filename with the response.

Comment: You're a wizard! Thank you! In my case, when the file is stored it is actually named with a 32 bit md5 type of value, but I do keep a record of the original file name, including the file extension. So where you have `pathinfo($fileRecord->file_path, PATHINFO_BASENAME)`, I simply have `$fileRecord->original_name`, and that seems to work just fine as well. Thanks again.

Comment: Though, for the record, with my method there is a warning message in the console (in Chrome at least): `Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream:` but it still works fine.

Comment: You could fix that warning by using [`finfo::buffer`](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.finfo-buffer.php) to get the mime type of the file from the decrypted string (assuming that information was encrypted with the contents) and passing that along with the response. I've updated my answer to include that.

Comment: Is there any way to do this with the [Laravel media library package](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-medialibrary/v7/introduction)?

Answer (score 3):

Laravel 5.6 allows you to use streams for downloads: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#file-downloads

So in your case:

```
return $response()->streamDownload(function() use $decryptedContents {
    echo $decryptedContents;
}, $fileName);
```