# Laravel 5.1 - Display images stored in Storage folder

Tags: php, laravel

I am making a image uploading function for a website using Laravel 5.1. Because of security problems, I want to store those images in `/storage/app` folder, instead of `/public`. Image's URL, for example:

```
/storage/app/images/<image_name>
```

In order to get image from `/storage/app`, I set up a specific route for this:

```
http://app.com/image/<image_name>
```

To point image requests to `/storage`:

```
Route::controllers([
    'image' => 'Frontend\ImageController',
]);
```

In `ImageController`, here is the code to create response:

```
public function missingMethod($filename = [])
{
    if (is_array($filename)) {
        $filename = implode('/', $filename);
    }
    // storage_path('app') - path to /storage/app folder
    $path = storage_path('app') . '/' . $filename;
    $file = \File::get($path);
    $type = \File::mimeType($path);

    return \Response::make($file,200)
        ->header("Content-Type", $type);
}
```

My problem is, after using this route to retrieve images, I can't display them in my view. There were no 404, 500 or any error status codes, request URL was it supposed to be, but it just showed a broken image icon. Is there anything wrong with my code?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 - How to access image uploaded in storage within View?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191330/laravel-5-how-to-access-image-uploaded-in-storage-within-view)

Comment: I tried it but the image can't be displayed, as mentioned above

Comment: Can the file be read by the HTTP server? Is there a reason why you've implemented the image handling in the `missingMethod` method? Because that method accepts one argument and it's an array of parameters, not the `$filename` like you've defined it. Have you tried the symbolic link approach?

Comment: Firefox said that 'Could not load the image'... I haven't tried the symbolic link approach yet because I prefer Laravel-based method. Maybe I will give it a try @@

Comment: You might find [this discussion](https://laracasts.com/forum/?p=707-laravel-load-images-stored-outside-public-folder/0) helpful, especially the last couple posts.

Comment: @camelCase thanks, but that solution gives me them same result :(

Comment: What have you tried to debug it? What happens when you echo out the methods parameters ($filename)? Are they what you expect? As @bogdan says, the `missingMethod` method only takes a single parameter (an array of parameters), so you should expect `$filename` to be an array not a string.

Comment: @Jeemusu I have edited the controller code to accept param as array. My input $filename and the produced $path are all correct as the desired image.

Comment: @xlKD I copied your code into a fresh laravel install. Works fine, so it's probably something to do with your setup, permissions, etc. The image shows in the network tab with a 200 status message? what does the preview/response tab show?

Comment: @Jeemusu thank you for quick response... Recently I even tried with images inside /public but the problem still remains @@ Here is a part of my response header:
    `HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Server: nginx/1.8.0
    Content-Type: image/png
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Connection: keep-alive
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Date: Wed, 13 Jan 2016 06:11:43 GMT`

Comment: The fact that it's happening with all images suggests it could be an issue with your nginx setup/settings. Try tagging the question with `nginx`. The only other suggestion I have is check folder/file permissions.

Comment: Hmm I think so... Guess I need some research about nginx. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, a php scripts in my `/config` folder has leading space, and that caused the http response failed @@ Such a nonsense mistake... Thank you all for your help!