# Get the assets from another directory in laravel 5

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, assets

We made a modulized app in laravel 5.0, So we want to get our css and js files from another directory (non public directory) such as a module directory.
We searched the stacks and couldn't find any solution. How can we do that?
Thanks

hint: the asset() function doesn't work except in public directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You have two options:**

1.You can setup a route to serve files from your directory.

```
Route::get('assets/{filename}', function ($filename){
    $path =  'path_to_your_folder/'.$filename;

    $file = File::get($path);
    $type = File::mimeType($path);

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type", $type);

    return $response;
});
```

2.Make a symbolic link between the directories.

```
ln -s /path/to/your_assets_folder /path/to/public/assets
```

Got it from: [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191330/laravel-5-how-to-access-image-uploaded-in-storage-within-view)

Answer (score 0):

Use url function `url('your_address')`