# Laravel how to get a image path?

Tags: php, laravel

Hi i'm new using Laravel and i have a form with a upload file button, but this is optional on my form, if i don't want to upload an image, my app stores one by default (no-image.jpg) and this image is in my storage_path, how i can get this path and assign it to my new record?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
if($request->infopath == null){
    $request->infopath = public_path() . "/infopath"."/". 'no-image.jpg';
    PreguntaAbierta::create($request->all());
    Session::flash('store-success','Datos agregados correctamente!');
    return redirect()->route('abierta.index');
}
```

**'SOLUTION'**

I finally found a solution , although an unorthodox but it does what I want, but I doubt remains =/
On my view:

```
  @if($pregunta->infopath == null)
     <td><img src="infopath/no-image.jpg" alt="" style="width:100px"/></td>
  @endif
```

LOL

Comment: NOTE: i edited my storage_path() to public_path() but i think that this does not affect?

Comment: This looks an answer to your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191330/laravel-5-how-to-access-image-uploaded-in-storage-within-view

Answer (score 0):

You can use `->with`

```
return redirect()->route('abierta.index')->with('infopath',$request->infopath);
```

and get this as $infopath in `abierta.index`

Also there is multiple option you can check here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses

Comment: Ty for ur reply, but i want to store an image by default when i don't upload one, my issue on this line :
$request->infopath = public_path() . "/infopath"."/". 'no-image.jpg';
it dont saves my default image

Comment: did you tried to change like this : `$infopath = public_path() . "/infopath"."/". 'no-image.jpg';` instead of `$request->infopat` may be this is protected and we can't change it.

Comment: Nop, neither.. when i print a real image path, it returns me: C:\xampp\tmp\php35E3.tmp it is generated for an image, i think that this is the path that i need, but i dont know how to get this ..

Comment: I think you should use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` instead of \ or /

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$input = $request->all();
$input['infopath'] = $your_image_public_path;
PreguntaAbierta::create($input);
```