# Laravel API return image from public folder with database data

Tags: api, laravel

I want to return image with data.

```
$ads = DB::table('ads')->whereRaw('category_id=' .$id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

$filename = public_path().'/uploads/images/'.$ads->ad_image;
$filename = (file_get_contents($filename));
$image = Array('image'=>json_encode(base64_encode($filename)));
$ads[0]->image = $image;

return $ads;
```

Comment: why not store image on server and return its path?

Comment: do you want to transmit whole image via json ? Or I'm not understanding your question..

Comment: Yes i am transmit the whole image in JSON

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you want to show the images to the user on the page stored in laravel's storage directory, You can do the following implementation:

Create a controller to fetch and return the image as a response.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
Use DB;


class PhotoController extends Controller
{
    public function image($fileName){
        $path = public_path().'/uploads/images/'.$fileName;
        return Response::download($path);        
    }
}
```

Add the Route to handle the image request

```
Route::get('image/{filename}',PhotoController @image);
```

Now, to access the image , lets say in image tag

```
<img src="image/abc.jpg">
```

**PS:** This method of serving images will have little overhead with respect to direct link of image...
In case, your images are public, you can simply create symbolic link of the directory where you have stored the images into the public directory.

Comment: Thanks. I am storing in public folder.

Comment: If privacy of the images doesn't mater use the symbolic links

Comment: Can you please share symbolic link of the directory I am storing the images into the public directory. It will access in Andriod and IOS Aps also.

Comment: @Anwar in linux you can create the symbolic link by using this command
`ln -s /path/to/laravel/storage/avatars /path/to/laravel/public/avatars`
more info :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191330/laravel-5-how-to-access-image-uploaded-in-storage-within-view

Answer (score 0):

$filename = asset('/uploads/images/'.$ads->ad_image);