# Best way to store images in database and display directly from database in model?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

What is the the best way to store and display images in the model directly from the database. I do not want to save to local storage or load from database in the controller and then pass to model. If possible.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To know the most safe and secure way to store and access images you should see this answer - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39748377/laravel-access-images-outside-public-folder/39753487#39753487)

I hope this will help you!