# How can I access in views, images from storage folder in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, storage

I have some images stored in the following paths:

```
/storage/app/public/uploads/users/2/avatar/0d8c18a52732bc9b0068102338fbf29b.jpeg
```

or

```
/storage/app/public/uploads/users/3/avatar/0d123dfd32bc9b0068102338fbf29b.jpeg
```

I had this paths stored in the users table. How can I display it in my `view.blade.php file`  ? I tried smth like this:

```
<img src="{{ url('/') }}{{ $user->avatar }}" alt="avatar">
```

But the image is not found on this path. Any idea ?

Comment: The image has to be in your "public" folder ... the browser do not see anything thats not in that public by default configuration.
look here --> http://tutsnare.com/upload-files-in-laravel/

Comment: I saw a lot if examples , there are storing files in the storage folder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39748377/laravel-access-images-outside-public-folder or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191330/laravel-5-how-to-access-image-uploaded-in-storage-within-view

Comment: take a look at this https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem#file-urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the syntax as

```
<img src='{{ asset("path-to-your-file") }}' alt='avatar'>
```

instead

```
<img src="{{ url('/') }}{{ $user->avatar }}" alt="avatar">
```

`asset()` points to public folder. `path-to-your-file` means the rest of the path

**Edit**

Additionally I have previously posted a similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41972141/3918473). Please take a look at it too.

Comment: by path-to-your-file, do you mean full path ?

Comment: This is generated: http://myproject.local/storage/app/public/uploads/users/2/avatar/0d8c18a52732bc9b0068102338fbf29b.jpeg. but i got 404. If i accessed it browser I got this: `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:`

Comment: can you open the file in your browser by putting in this :
`http://your-url//uploads/users/2/avatar/0d8c18a52732bc9b0068102338fbf29b.jpeg`

Comment: I did that , and I get routing issues:  `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161`

Comment: I changed into this `<img src="{{ asset('storage/app/public/uploads/users/2/avatar/0d8c18a52732bc9b0068102338fbf29b.jpeg') }}" alt="avatar">` but i still got that routing issue. I guess I need smth to add to the routing file: web.php .Im not sure what exactly ...

Comment: There is a similar answer which I posted earlier. Take a look at it.

Comment: I had to used this: `php artisan storage:link` it will generate a symlink

Comment: Yes I figured it. That's why I gave you the like. Glad It worked for you

Comment: Thank you  for the help , highly appreciated ! :P