# Storage Directory image show in view and also download in laravel 5.3

Tags: filesystems, laravel-5.3

**I saved my images in storage folder successfully.**
my image path is below in storage folder "**storage/app/**".
Now i want to show image in views and also i want to download images there.
For showing image i write below code in views but image not show.
Please help me why image not show....

```
 <img src="<?php echo asset('storage/'.$row->file_name.'/'); ?>"  class="img-responsive" />
```

below my controller function.

```
public function store(Request $request)
        {
            $model = new FilesModel();

            if($request->file('file_name'))
            {
               $filename = $request->file_name;
               $files  = $filename->getClientOriginalName();
              Storage::disk('local')->put($files ,'centent');
              $model->file_name = $files ;
            }
           $model->save();
            return redirect('files');
        }
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191330/laravel-5-how-to-access-image-uploaded-in-storage-within-view

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 - How to access image uploaded in storage within View?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191330/laravel-5-how-to-access-image-uploaded-in-storage-within-view)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `asset()` helper function to retrieve a file saved in the `storage` directory.
Normally `asset()` function points to your public directory, therefore in this case it is looking for your file in `public/storage/app/file.ext`. I suggest you change from `asset()` to `storage_path()` and then you can access the image like:

```
<img src="<?php echo storage_path('app/'.$row->file_name.'/'); ?>"  class="img-responsive" />
```

Comment: can you try with inspect element and tell me what the img src looks like?

Comment: continuously three days i search solution but still my problem not solve kindly tell me whats the problem