# laravel get storage image

Tags: php, laravel, url, storage

I using ajax get the data and append to html in my div, the code likes..

```
var r = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
var append =  '<img src="{{ asset('storage/app/item') }}/' + r.image+'">';
```

And the image url getting an error path message

http://www.example.com/storage/app/item/item-1.jpg

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

What the problem is?
How can I get the right url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image are on the storage and you only have access to the public folder, because of that, you need to create a symlink to make it accessible

`ln -s /path/to/laravel/storage/app/item /path/to/laravel/public/item`

Now you can use the asset in your view and retrieve the image

`{{ asset('app/item') }}`

Similar topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191330/laravel-5-how-to-access-image-uploaded-in-storage-within-view)