# Laravel 5.4 show uploaded image issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm learning `Laravel 5.4` and for now I'm trying to upload image and show uploaded image in `html`.

It seems files are uploaded successfully but when I want to show the image in `Html`, there's 404 error for images and nothing will display.

This is my settings and code:

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name'  => 'required|string|max:255',
            'desc'  => 'required|string',
            'width' => 'required|numeric',
            'height'=> 'required|numeric',
            'artist'=> 'required|exists:artists,id',
            'photo' => 'required|file'
        ]);

        $artistInfo = Artist::find($request->artist);

        $fileExtension = $request->file('photo')->extension();

        $originalFileName = $request->file('photo')->getClientOriginalName();

        $filePath = Storage::putFile('public', $request->file('photo'), 'public');


        Photo::create([
            'name'      => $request->name,
            'origName'  => $originalFileName,
            'url'       => $filePath,
            'artist_id' => $request->artist,
            'desc'      => $request->desc,
            'width'     => $request->width,
            'height'    => $request->height
        ]);

        return $filePath;//this for test
    }
```

**And my Blade:**

```
                @forelse($photos as $photo)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $photo->name }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <img class="img" src="{{ asset( 'public/storage/' . $photo->url) }}" alt="{{ $photo->name }}" /></td>
                        <td>{{ $photo->artist->name . ' ' . $photo->artist->family }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $photo->desc }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $photo->width }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $photo->height }}</td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <a href="{{ route('artists.edit', ['id' => $photo->id]) }}">
                                <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <a href="{{ route('artists.edit', ['id' => $photo->id]) }}">
                                <i class="material-icons">assignment_turned_in</i>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @empty
                    <tr>
                        <td>There's no photo Yet</td>
                        <td>&mdash;</td>
                        <td>&mdash;</td>
                        <td>&mdash;</td>
                        <td>&mdash;</td>
                    </tr>
                @endforelse
```

***NOTE :***

I made a symbol link to my public folder using `php artisan storage:link` and symlink works fine...

I changed this line in blade:

```
<img class="img" src="{{ asset( 'public/storage/' . $photo->url) }}" alt="{{ $photo->name }}" /></td>
```

and tried these manners:

```
 <img class="img" src="{{ asset(storage_path() . ($photo->url)) }}" alt="{{ $photo->name }}" /></td>


 <img class="img" src="{{ storage_path() . ($photo->url) }}" alt="{{ $photo->name }}" /></td>
```

`$photo->url` has image filename for example `jDHPOTh7iejFABANSzasNbBWJ09DqLbqJb8ymJhv.png`

Would you please let me know which part is my problem?

***Thanks in Advance***

***UPDATE :***

I'm using `PhpStorm` Ide and when I download my public folder to my project -or synchronize this- my symbol link does not appear in public folder list...

**This is `ls` from my public folder :**

[image: list of folders in public]

And this is my phpStorm project view **AFTER** download a fresh copy of public folders in my host:

[image: Folder list inside my IDE]

***And as a note :***
I started to develop this website in windows at first and then I did move entire project to my linux remote server...

Comment: Tried `{{ asset( 'public/') .'/'. $photo->url }}` ?

Comment: @linktoahref Yep, but didn't work...!

Comment: I think this could work as you are trying to get the path using the generated id  `{{ storage_path($photo->url) }} `

Comment: I tried that before... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all for participating, but in my case there was a tricky issue...

I was logged in to my server using `root` and when I did type `php artisan storage:link`, the symbol link was made by `root` as `owner` and it seems Apache didn't have permission to access this symbol link and because of that, the files was not accessible in `http`.

**SOLUTION**

I have a vds that serve 5 different websites, so
I did simply change the owner of symbol link's owner to my relative username and the problem solved...

```
chown -R usergroup:username /path/to/link
```

That's it...

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for answer to this question, please follow this link contains great answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30191854/417899

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is here:

```
$filePath = Storage::putFile('public', $request->file('photo'), 'public');
```

here you are putting your file on `public` folder and here:

```
<img class="img" src="{{ asset( 'public/storage/' . $photo->url) }}" alt="{{ $photo->name }}" /></td>
```

you are trying to get it from `public/storage/`. So change the path like:

```
<img class="img" src="{{ asset( 'public/' . $photo->url) }}" alt="{{ $photo->name }}" /></td>
```

and try again.

**Note:** Here uploaded images path is stored in `public/image.extension`, so fetching it from the same `public` directory

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what's your suggestion? I tried so many different manner...