# How to retrieve the images stored in storage folder of laravel5.4?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**Storage/app/public**-->This is my storage path of an images.

**Controller code:**

```
public function addDeviceCategory(Request $cform)
{

if (Input::hasFile('imagefile'))
    {
    $name  = $this->getImageId().".".$cform->file('imagefile')-
 >getClientOriginalExtension();   

    $image = $cform->file('imagefile');        
    $resize = Image::make($image)->resize(700, 300)->encode($cform-
 >file('imagefile')->getClientOriginalExtension());
    $hash = md5($resize->__toString());

    $path = "public/" . $name;
    Storage::put($path, $resize->__toString());

    }
  $validation1=deviceCategory::select('deviceCategoryName')-
 >where("deviceCategoryName",$cform->deviceCategory)->first();

    if(is_null($validation1))
    {

    $temp=new deviceCategory;

    $temp->deviceCategoryId=$this->getDeviceCategoryId();
    $temp->deviceCategoryName=$cform->input('deviceCategory');
    $temp->subCategoryId=$cform->input('subCategory');
    $temp->image=$name;

    $temp->save();

    return redirect('formAddDeviceCategory');
   }
```

}

```
public function getImageId(){
  return md5(uniqid().microtime());
}
```

This is the way I'm storing the images into storage path of laravel(ie. Storage/app/public).The storage done successfully here.

View Code:

```
 @php 
            $l=1
            @endphp
            @foreach($cdetails as $cdetail)
            <tr>
              <td>{{$l++}}</td>
              <td>{{$cdetail->deviceCategoryId}}</td>
              <td>{{$cdetail->categoryName}}</td>
              <td>{{$cdetail->subCategoryName}}</td>
              <td>{{$cdetail->deviceCategoryName}}</td>

          **<td><img src="{{ asset('storage/app/public/$cdetail->
              image') }}"  width="50" height="50"></img></td>**
             @endforeach
```

Here I am trying to display the stored image.But nothing displays there.

Comment: Tried `{{ asset($cdetail->image) }}` ?

Comment: Yes. But it displays only the images stored in public folder

Comment: sorry my bad! I was a bit ignorant

Comment: Its Okay.Cooool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you have linked the `storage/app/public` to `public/storage`.

If not run `php artisan storage:link`

Then in your view use `Storage::url('public/' . $cdetail->image)` to get the link.

Comment: I had already run the link command. It shows that directory already exist.

Comment: @nishanthi then try using asset(Storage::url($cdetail->image)) to get the image.

Comment: sorry,It doesn't displays

Comment: Whats the output of `Storage::url($cdetail->image)`. Also whats a value 
 of `$cdetail->image` stored in database

Comment: $cdetail->image gives the image name which is the same stored in db

Comment: Also I have tried asset(Storage::url($cdetail->image)) in the image tag.

Comment: Can you post a sample value stored in the database

Comment: 0ee84b65074cddd373426b8f0c85a44c.png

Comment: Try this `asset(Storage::url('public/' . $cdetail->image))`

Comment: Yes, `<img src="{{ asset(Storage::url('public/' . $cdetail->image)) }}"  width="50" height="50"/>`.

Comment: Sorry.Nothing is changed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151694/discussion-between-chanafdo-and-nishanthi).

Answer (score 0):

Use asset() function like

example in your blade template: 
`{{ asset('storage/app/public/'.$cdetail->image ) }}`

In case if you want to access in your controller
`asset('storage/app/public/'.$cdetail->image );`

```
<td>
   <img src="{{ asset('storage/app/public/'.$cdetail->image) }}" width="50" 
    height="50"></img>
</td>
```

Comment: why $imageName is used. I am retrieving it from db

Comment: In controller where should I need to do this -->(asset('storage/app/public/'.$cdetail->
              image );) change

Comment: Yes, I just referring by that you will put your image name which you retrieving from your DB.

Comment: If you want to access it, in any case, that's why I mentioned that you can also access by that in your controller

Comment: Sorry, I don't know where to include this asset('storage/app/public/'.$cdetail->image );

Comment: Did you got your result?

Comment: I have made the changes, but didn't get the output. But in my view source page it appears like this-->http://localhost/AdminPanel/public/storage/app/public/iTunesArtwork.png. When I click on the click  it shows NOt found Http Exception

Comment: Did you checked that your file name is same in the folder that you have in db. And try to use your System IP instead of localhost

Comment: yes.I just renamed the file name and stored it in db

Comment: The link you gave me, it seems to be wrong because it should be like 
http://localhost/AdminPanel/storage/app/public/iTunesArtwork.png

Comment: Nishanti come to chat session, we can discuss there 
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151682/discussion-between-saroj-and-nishanthi

Answer (score -1):

I think you can try this:

```
<img src="{{ storage_path('app/public/$cdetail->
              image') }}"  width="50" height="50"></img>
```

Comment: In my view source page it appears like this-->**   <td><img src="/var/www/html/AdminPanel/storage/app/public/$cdetail-&gt;
              image"   width="50" height="50"></img></td>**

Comment: @nishanthi Ok let me check it

Comment: Yeah ok sir.Thanks in advance

Comment: @nishanthi Please follow this link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191330/laravel-5-how-to-access-image-uploaded-in-storage-within-view) and try

Comment: @nishanthi And let me know this solution work for you or not

Comment: Ok. I ll try and let you know

Comment: @nishanthi Sure

Comment: I have tried your reference link. But it doesn't works

Comment: Also I m trying it with POST

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151763/discussion-between-nishanthi-and-addweb-solution-pvt-ltd).