# Laravel Accessing Images Stored in Storage Directory

Tags: laravel

I want to access some images to display in a blade file, but they're stored in `/storage/app/content/img`.

I've come across a few [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191330/laravel-5-how-to-access-image-uploaded-in-storage-within-view) using symbolic links , but their solutions haven't worked for me.

**BLADE FILE**

```
<td>
  @if( !empty($entry->{$column['name']}) )
    <a href="storage/app/content/img/filename.jpg">
      <img src="storage/app/content/img/filename.jpg"/>
    </a>
</td>
```

**WHEN I TRIED SYMBOLIC LINKS - ROUTE**

```
Route::get('/img/{filename}', function ($filename)
{
    $path = storage_path() . '/app/content/img/' . $filename;

    if(!File::exists($path)) abort(404);

    $file = File::get($path);
    $type = File::mimeType($path);

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type", $type);
    return $response;
})->name('avatar');
```

**BLADE FILE**

```
<td>
  @if( !empty($entry->{$column['name']}) )
    <a href="/img/filename.jpg">
      <img src="/img/filename.jpg"/>
    </a>
</td>
```

Comment: What's the problem? 404 or something else?

Comment: Yes, takes me to the 404 page

Comment: Did you try printing out `$path` and making sure that path exists?

Comment: With the route thing I get: SignatureException in Signature.php line 42:
Signature is missing.

Comment: Where do I put `$path`? The blade file?

Comment: It's your code, shouldn't you know where $path resides?  (The route).  You have two different examples here, I'm referring to the bottom one.  The top one won't work unless storage resides in public/.  However, it's a bad idea to create a symlink from public/storage to storage since storage contains a lot of files you likely don't want to publicly expose.

Comment: Secondly, why don't you just put these files in the public folder rather than storage?

Comment: I meant for printing it, but I figured it out.I can't answer that, picking up the project after somebody else already organized that stuff

Comment: You can't change that logic to save to the public folder instead?

Comment: Not sure what that might break. Its using Glide image library which is all set up to the storage directory

Comment: Well, you could always create a symlink in the reverse direction after you move it.. (from storage to public)  Apache or the web server may have issues with symlinks but the filesystem shouldn't.

Comment: @cvassios was the symlink created successfully? If yes what do you have in the symlink (storage) folder in your public directory?

Comment: did you load url in browser ? and also tried dd($path) in your route file.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you use the `asset` helper:

```
asset('img/file.png');
```

Comment: How would this help/what does it do? Laravel documentation on it is pretty vague