# How to open file from storage by URL address?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I store files in storage.

No I tried to generate link that open file like:

```
http://[temp.com]/storage/tests/de139607636857fade861a3c2c472643.txt
```

But it does not work.

How to open file from storage by URL address?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Files in the storage are not accessible by url by default

You could use [Public Disk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#the-public-disk). For that you need to create symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`

From Larvel 5.3 and up, you have artisan command that will help you to create symlink

`php artisan storage:link`

If you are using older version of Laravel, you can find an answer how to create symbolic link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191330/laravel-5-how-to-access-image-uploaded-in-storage-within-view/30192351#30192351)

---

Another approach would be to create new disk "uploads", by editing the file `config/filesystems.php`

```
'disks' => [
    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => storage_path(),
    ],
    'uploads' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => public_path() . '/uploads',
    ],
]
```

To store files in this location

```
Storage::disk('uploads')->put($file_name, $file_content);
```

And to get the file

```
asset('uploads/'. $file_name)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `storage` directory exists outside the web root, as some of the stuff in there shouldn't necessarily be publicly accessible.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#the-public-disk

> The public disk is intended for files that are going to be publicly accessible. By default, the public disk uses the local driver and stores these files in `storage/app/public`. To make them accessible from the web, you should create a symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`. This convention will keep your publicly accessible files in one directory that can be easily shared across deployments when using zero down-time deployment systems like Envoyer.

Comment: Then how to be? Can I make link to storage directory using htaccess?

Comment: This is full path to files: `/public_html/storage/app/tests`

Comment: That is not the standard structure for a Laravel app. Does `public_html/storage/app/tests/de139607636857fade861a3c2c472643.txt` exist? Can the webserver's user access it? Why are you not using Laravel's built-in locations and functionality for this?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend not to modify the Laravel's directory structure.

What I would do is to create a URL to download the file, for example:

```
Route::get('download/{file}', 'DownloadsController@index');
```

And in that method's controller, put some logic to assert that the file exists and serve it with a response download, for example

```
public function index($file)
{
    $filePath = storage_path('tests/'.$file);
    if (! file_exists($filePath)) {
        // Some response with error message...
    }

    return response()->download($filePath);
}
```

Then you can download your file with a link like this

```
http://[temp.com]/download/de139607636857fade861a3c2c472643.txt
```

The controller's way allows you to make some authentication checks before serving the file for example, or to count how many times the file was downloaded.

Comment: While this does allow for extra functionality, I prefer @ljubadr's answer. Proxying files through Laravel requires more resources than a static file download handled by the webserver.