# Moving file: can't find correct path

Tags: php, laravel

I work with Laravel 5.3. I have created `file.txt` in public directory and want to move it. In tinker console I execute commands:

```
>>> $path = public_path() . '/file.txt';
=> "/home/jan/fun/tad/public/file.txt"
>>> $newPath = public_path() . '/new_folder/file.txt';
=> "/home/jan/fun/tad/public/new_folder/file.txt"
>>> Storage::move($path, $newPath);
League\Flysystem\FileNotFoundException with message 'File not found at path: home/jan/fun/tad/public/file.txt'
```

I have tried different combinations, none worked.

How should I construct correct path?

Comment: It didn't work because file was not found ;)

Comment: You have hit the nail on the head.

Comment: By default, the public disk uses the local driver and stores these files in folder **storage/app/public** not your **public** folder.. Take a look at [The Public Disk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#the-public-disk)

Comment: You can use * if (file_exists($filename)) { *

Comment: Can you try using `rename($path, $newPath);` ?

Comment: @Cedroux this have worked. That's weird, because `Storage::move()` is just an wrapper around php's `rename()`

Comment: @janjanjan `Storage` expects paths that are **relative** to **'default'** driver that is set in **config/filesystems.php**. And if if you didn't change anything it's set to `storage_path('app/public')`, which is **storage/app/public**. If you want to use `Storage` with just **public/** folder, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46799674/3226121), part where it says **Another approach would be to create new disk...*