# laravel 5.5 get file url from storage

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I am working on a project in which i want to get the link of the file which i uploaded in the storage-app-public directory of laravel. I followed this link [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191330/laravel-5-how-to-access-image-uploaded-in-storage-within-view), but when I try to run following command in Vagrant:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

It gives following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
There are no commands defined in the "storage" namespace.
```

Comment: Just use this in your PHP : `$path = storage_path('folder/'. $filename)`

Comment: Make sure you are using Laravel +5.3: `php artisan --version`

Comment: @troyer i am using laravel 5.5

Comment: If you run `php artisan` do you see the command in the list?

Comment: @vincentdecaux I got the link now issue is when i try to access the file through that link it shows NotFoundHttpException message.

Comment: @troyer i just ran the command and it is not in that list.

Comment: It's a 5.5 fresh installation or it was upgraded?

Comment: @troyer its a fresh installation with lumen

Comment: @troyer i am running it in vagrant.

Comment: @shahzebakram Looks like something is mess up, if it's a fresh installation I would recommend you to reinstall it.

Comment: @troyer is there some other way?

Answer (score 0):

you need to follow this code, I think It will be helpful for you.

```
$imageTempName = $userdata->file('image_media')->getPathname();
$imageName = $userdata->file('image_media')->getClientOriginalName();
```

upload the file to the database within the directory using Laravel.

```
<?php
public static function upload_file(Request $userdata){
    $imageTempName = $userdata->file('image_media')->getPathname();
    $imageName = $userdata->file('image_media')->getClientOriginalName();
    $path = base_path() . '/public/uploads/images/';
    $userdata->file('image_media')->move($path , $imageName);
    $data=array('media'=>$imageName);
    $insert=with(new UserModel)->uploadFile($data);
}
?>
```

Comment: I want to store file in storage directory.

Comment: Create a folder under the public directory and apply this code. you must put the upload directory path in the code.