# Display image from storage folder laravel 5.5

Tags: php, image, laravel-5, phpmyadmin

I am working with laravel 5.5 and from there i store images on the storage folder which is later linked in public folder. For this project i have copied all the files from public folder inside the root and the project files exist on the project folder. Locally I can make a a symlink with the command  php artisan storage:link but here (on shared hosting) I don't know how. I cant display the images if there is no symlink.

Comment: does your shared hosting have cpanel?

Comment: No it doesn't have

Comment: what does it have? ssh?. Either way, look here ->  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191330/laravel-5-how-to-access-image-uploaded-in-storage-within-view/30192351#30192351

Comment: Not even ssh. It has ssl/tls

Comment: My webhosting required to add all public files into the "/" and all the other in the "/project". This is the way that i uploaded and website works but I can not make a symlink of the storage folder, i have no idea how because I dont have the public folder and i cant run any commands. I tried creating script but it doesnt work.