# Display stored image in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image, display

I am new to this, I have stored image in public/storage but I can't figure out how to display it.

I have this function in UploadController:

```
public function store(request $request)
{
    if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
        $request->file('file');
        return $request->file->store('public');
    }

    return 'No file selected';
}
```

This in web.php:

```
Route::get('/', 'UploadController@index');
Route::post('store', 'UploadController@store');
```

And this in welcome.blade.php:

```
   {!! Form::open(['url' => '/store', 'method' => 'post', 'files' => true]) !!} 
   File name:
   {!! Form::text('episode') !!}  
   {!! Form::file('file'); !!} 
   {!! Form::submit('Upload File') !!} 
   {!! Form::token() !!}
   {!! Form::close() !!}
```

It displays name of the saved file in /store

Can anyone please give me an advice how to display the image?

Comment: See this previous post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191330/laravel-5-how-to-access-image-uploaded-in-storage-within-view?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'$request->file->store('public');' will return a path to your saved file with a unique name so save the returned path in your database or where ever like below:

```
 $path = $request->file->store('public');
```

Now $path variable contains path (url) to your saved file.
And use this path to display your stored image.