# Laravel 5.5 image is not showing from storage/app

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel 5.5. I have a form to upload image. Those images are storing into the `storage/app` folder. It is working fine. But when I try to show those images. Those are not showing. 
I have tried with those ways to print my images.

`<img src="{{ asset('storage/1539872957.a-nice-place-to-picnic.jpg')}}" alt="">
<img class="user_avatar" src="{{ url('storage/app/1539872897.IMG_20180804_120323.jpg') }}">
<img class="user_avatar" src="<?php echo asset('storage/1539455504.prakruth-resort.jpg');?>">`

Here I am giving image name as static name just for checking.

I have also done `php artisan storage:link` and a shortcut folder named 'storage' is created in the public folder. But still images are not showing.

Comment: They have to be in storage/app/public

Comment: What is the source url formed when image is loaded in browser?

Comment: @IvanJelev even it is not allowing me to upload file outside storage/app folder. I have modified filesystem.php folder . But still those are storing to the storage/app folder. So I want to show them from this folder.

Comment: @KamalPaliwal 
Here is the output `<img src="http://localhost:8000/storage/1539872957.a-nice-place-to-picnic.jpg" alt="">` `<img class="user_avatar" src="http://localhost:8000/storage/app/1539872897.IMG_20180804_120323.jpg">` `<img class="user_avatar" src="http://localhost:8000/storage/1539455504.prakruth-resort.jpg">`

Comment: When you accessing /storage/image.jpg your image have to be in laravelFolder/storage/app/public folder not in storage/app. Example: /www/laravel/storage/app/public/image1.jpg

Comment: These images should be stored in storage/app/public folder after that symlinks will work properly. You can use Laravel File Storage (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem), it will provide you functions to upload the images at proper location

Answer (score 0):

i think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191330/laravel-5-how-to-access-image-uploaded-in-storage-within-view) Answer would help you.

you will have to create symlink from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public` first through this command

```
`php artisan storage:link`
```

Now any file in `/storage/app/public` can be accessed via a link like:

`http://somedomain.com/storage/image.jpg`

In your Controller use public driver like this:

```
 \Storage::disk('public')->put('file.png',file_get_contents($request->file->getRealPath()));
```

the above file.png would be stored in 'public/storage'.

now you can access the image file like this:

`<img src="{{ asset('storage/file.png'); }}" />`