# Thumbnail images not showing

Tags: laravel, eloquent, phpmyadmin, laravel-5

i will be glad if anyone can help.

[code line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRWYs.jpg)

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPBLd.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you ran `php artisan storage:link`? This is usually what does it for me.

[Laravel 5 - How to access image uploaded in storage within View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191330/laravel-5-how-to-access-image-uploaded-in-storage-within-view)

Comment: Are you using HTTPS to serve your application? Can you share the path that prints out in the browser (in the src="" attribute), and also the error you receive in the console?

Comment: Sure, am using localhost http.
               
       src="http://localhost/Project/storage/images/profile/boss1550427195.jpg"

Comment: If you type `localhost/Project/storage/images/profile/boss1550427195.jpg` into a new browser window does the image display?

Comment: What is the url for your homepage? Is it `localhost` or is it `localhost/Project`? If you type `localhost/storage/images/profile/boss1550427195.jpg` does it display your image?

Comment: The problem was /profile instead of /images. Bro i really appreciate you help your questions have made me discover my mistake. Thanks alot. I really appreciate