# Access to the storage folder in Laravel is impossible

Tags: php, laravel, docker, laravel-5, laradock

I have Laradock on my MacBook.

I make php artisan storage: link

My website is this URL: http://project1.test

My website upload files to storage/.

When I open in browser: http://project1.test/storage/my-file-name.jpg
I have error: 404 NOT FOUND

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Did you try to "echo asset('storage/my-file-name.txt');" to find out your file path?

Comment: for upload and all other files which are used by the site users, the proper directory is PUBLIC. uploading the file in STORAGE is wrong. please switch to public and user publuc_path() function to access the location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1: create a symlink**

you can not access files located in  `storage` directory directly via URL!  Only files located in `public` folder would be available publicity. So you should make a symlink in public folder pointing the directory or file (within storage folder) you want to share. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30191854/5458806)

**Solution 2:**

Just upload the files in `public` folder!

Comment: Ahmad is correct that you can not access storage the way you are trying to.  However, a symlink is a bandaid solution. You should make routes and controllers that return things from Storage::disk

Comment: @TarekAdam I agree, thanks! I will  update the answer

Comment: @TarekAdam please take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30191854/5458806.    what is your opinion?

Comment: That artisan command would make it more deployable with githooks.  I'd never seen it before.  So I guess that puts me on the fence for this issue.

Comment: I make: php artisan storage:link, but it's not help

Comment: @trafgs  store the file in `storage/app/public`  not directly in `storage` folder