# How to give download option for image,pdf etc files stored in storage folder depending on type of file in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I am learning Laravel. I want to show image(give download option)/pdf(show name of pdf file and give download and view(view on browser, in new tab) option) depending on extension on my view.

I have `file_docs` table. In that table I have column `buyers_aadhar_file`. In that column I am storing files like image OR pdf. I am customising name of file while storing like "buyersid_B_aadhar_nameoffile.ext" e.g `2_B_aadhar_Aadhaar-Card-New-Rules-Update-644x362.jpg` or `3_B_aadhar_Aadhaar-Data-Update-Form-03.pdf`

Now I want to display that files depending on type of file.

If file is image then show image also give download option for image. And if file is pdf then show name of pdf file, give download and view pdf file option for that file.

How do I check on my view, whether that file is image or pdf and how to implement relative download and view option for that file?

Comment: get the file type from the suffix (.jpg, .pdf) ?

Comment: you could use php's path_info to get the details of the file, and their extension

Answer (score 0):

you could use `path_info`, a php function in the laravel view file to fetch the file extension and stuff like that 
and you could look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191330/laravel-5-how-to-access-image-uploaded-in-storage-within-view) link for image showing and pdf showing in your view file