# how to show images stored in local disk storage in lravel

Tags: laravel

I want to show the image that uploaded to local disk storage.
the file located at: storage/user/ directory.

```
 $url = Storage::url('users/file.jpg');
 $image="<img src='$url' />;
```

and return it to ajax and append it in the blade page.

```
      return response()->json(["response"=>$image]);
```

Comment: Are you getting the proper image url?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191330/laravel-5-how-to-access-image-uploaded-in-storage-within-view

Comment: yes I'm @Jayant

Comment: The local storage does not have an accessible URL. You'll need to use the public storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found how to show image that Stored in local disk of Storage in laravel:
Routes:

```
 Route::post('/clientarea/form/{id}/responses/individual', [ResponsesController::class,'individual']);

Route::get('/image/show/users/{userId}/{formId}/{fileName}',[ResponsesController::class,'showImage']);
```

ResponsesController::class,'individual' :

$answer is the path of image in local storage(local disk, not public disk)

```
$response.= "<img alt='image' title='image' class='answersImage' src='/image/show/$answer'>";
  return $response;
```

return respose and append it in the blade by jquery:

```
   success: function(data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
                 
                    $('#respContainer').html(response);
                    
                };
```

ResponsesController::class,'showImage'] :

```
$path='users/'.$userId.'/'.$formId.'/'.$filename;
     $file = Storage::get($path);
            $response = response()->make($file, 200);
            $response->header('Content-Type', 'image/jpg');
            return $response;
```

and It will show the image that Stored in local disk.

Comment: please look over my answer @Jayant

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this. I would like to change the JSON response first.
 `return response()->json(['data' => $image, 'status' => 'success', 'code' => 200]);`

In Ajax, once your file uploaded

```
$.ajax({
.
.
.
success : function (res) {
       if (res.code == 200) {
          $('#image').text(res.data);
      }
});
```

Add one tag `<p id="image"></p>` in blade file.

can change your file path in the `filesystems.php` file under the `config` folder.

````
   'local' => [ 'driver' => 'local',  'root' => storage_path('__FOLDER_PATH__'), ],
   'public' => ['driver'  => 'local',
                'root' => storage_path('__FOLDER_PATH__'),
                'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage', 
                'visibility' => 'public',],```
````

Comment: I think because the file located in local disk , not public disk. it is not accessible. I want to solve this issue. if I put the file in storage/public directory, it will be accessible publicly. But I don't want it be publicly accessible.

Comment: 'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path(''),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

Comment: you can change your storage path, make it configurable from `.env` and use it in `root` key in `filesystems.php`.