# View doesn't show the image on storage in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to show all images on my storage/app/livros folder on a view with this code below, but I get this [image: like I have nothing there]. How can I show these images?

```
@extends('layouts.app_cad_livros')
@section('content')
    <div class="textocs">
        <br>
        <h3>LIVROS</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card_livro">
        @foreach($livro as $mostra)
            {{$mostra->users_id}}

            <img src="{{ url("storage/app/livros{$mostra->image}") }}"
                 style="max-width=100px;">

            TÍTULO   {{$mostra->namel}}<br>
            AUTOR {{$mostra->autor}}<br>
            EDITORA {{$mostra->editora}}<br>
            CATEGORIA {{$mostra->categoria}}<br>
            CLASSIFICAÇÃO {{$mostra->classificação}}<br>
            DESCRIÇÃO {{$mostra->descricao}}<br>
            CAPA {{$mostra->image}}<br>
        @endforeach
    </div>
    <a href="{{ url('/alugar', $mostra->users_id)}}">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">quero alugar</button>
    </a>
@endsection
```

this is the

```
<img src="{{ url("storage/{$mostra->image}") }}"  style="max-width=100px;">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

and to access the image:

```
 asset('storage/app/path/to/image')
```

try this

```
asset('storage/app/livros/'.$mostra->image.')
```

or

```
asset('storage/app/livros/{$mostra->image}')
```

You can get more info [From Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191330/laravel-5-how-to-access-image-uploaded-in-storage-within-view)